# Django. Getting items, that are not listed

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    viewsT = models.ManyToManyField('PhotoViewT', symmetrical=False)
    ...

class PhotoViewT(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey('Photo', related_name="PhotoView")
    ...
```

I have to craft filter to get photos that are not already viewed. In "PhotoViewT" I store viewed photos. in other words need to get all photos excluding those are in "PhotoViewT" as "photo". Is it possible?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Why do you have a m2m rel in photo if you already have a reverse fk relationship?

Comment: Okay, I'll delete m2m, but what to do with query?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the photo ForeignKey on PhotoView and then this query should work:

```
Photo.objects.filter(viewsT__isnull=True)
```

Comment: On PhotoView I have user field. Need to choose items, those are not already viewed by any defined user.